# ERROR in The target entry-point "@auth0/angular-jwt" has missing dependencies:

Tags: javascript, c#, angular, npm

I have an angular project version:

```
@angular-devkit/architect    0.901.1
@angular-devkit/core         9.1.1
@angular-devkit/schematics   9.1.1
@schematics/angular          9.1.1
@schematics/update           0.901.1
rxjs                         6.5.4
```

After executing:
   @auth0/angular-jwt

I can not compile my project and it gives this error:

```
ERROR in The target entry-point "@auth0/angular-jwt" has missing dependencies:
 - tslib
 - @angular/core
 - rxjs/operators
 - rxjs
 - @angular/common/http
```

I am very new at angular, please help me. I already executed these commands:

```
npm install --save "package names"
```

but they gave errors.

Comment: try to remove your `package-lock.json` and re run `npm i`

Answer (score 3):

I had this same problem. As we are using the version of angular 9, we have to install version 4.2.0 of angular-jwt. According to their site:

**https://www.npmjs.com/package/@auth0/angular-jwt**

> @ auth0 / angular-jwt v5 is to be used with Angular v10 + and RxJS v6 +. For Angular v6 + to v9, use @ auth0 / angular-jwt v4

So:

1. Uninstall @auth0 (**npm uninstall @auth0/angular-jwt**)
2. Deleted the package-LOCK.json folder
3. Ran the compatible installation @auth for angular 9 (**npm install @auth0/angular-jwt@4.2.0**)

Now when I ran the **ng serve** it ran normally.

I hope I helped you. ;)